# jQuery Validate plugin - Using a variable in range method validation and error messaging

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and I am using the `range` method to require a number between `0` and `100` in my first input. In my second input I want to require a number that is between the number from the first input and `100`. For instance, if you enter `10` in the first input, then the range should be between `10` and `100` in the second input. If you were to enter `5` in the second input, there should be an error that says `Please enter a value between 10 and 100`. Is this possible?

```js
var rangeVal = null;

$('form').submit(function(e){
  return false;
});

$('#range').keyup(function() {
  rangeVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(rangeVal);
});

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        range: {
            range: [0, 100]
        },
        range2: {
          range: [rangeVal, 100]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        range: {
          range: "Please enter a value between 0 and 100"
        },
        range2: {
          range: "Please enter a value between " + rangeVal + " and 100"
        }
    }
});
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
  margin-top:10px;
}
input {
  display:block;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Range1 (0 - 100)
    <input id="range" name="range" type="number" />
  </label>
  <label>Range2 (Range1 - 100)
    <input id="range2" name="range2" type="number" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the rule to a function and using template params in the message:

```js
var rangeVal = null;

$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#range').keyup(function() {
  rangeVal = $(this).val();
});

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        range: {
            range: [0, 100]
        },
        range2: {
            range: function () {
                return [rangeVal, 100];
            }
        },
    },
    messages: {
        range: {
          range: "Please enter a value between 0 and 100"
        },
        range2: {
          range: "Please enter a value between {0} and 100"
        }
    }
});
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
  margin-top:10px;
}
input {
  display:block;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top:30px;
}
.error {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Range1 (0 - 100)
    <input id="range" name="range" type="number" />
  </label>
  <label>Range2 (Range1 - 100)
    <input id="range2" name="range2" type="number" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```